# d3 overlay object mousedown event handling

Tags: javascript, d3.js, events, svg, mousedown

I'm recently making network topology with d3.js

It has pan&zoom, object dragging, line drawing function.

I've implemented all functions now, but there is a problem.

When I draw line on main svg, it's drawing well.

But if I want to start drawing on the object(rect or some images), It's not working properly.

Because object dragging function swallow 'mousedown' event.

```
[Main svg]
mainSvg
       .on('mousedown', function mouseDown() {
                  // make object(line)
                })
                .on('mousemove', function mouseMove() {
                  // drawing line
                  // update line's x2, y2 coordinates
                })
                .on('mouseup', () => {
                  // drawing end
                });
[Object]
 .call(d3.drag()
                    .on('start', function dragStart() {
                    // make active state
                    })
                    .on('drag', function dragging(d) {
                    // update object's x,y coordinates
                    })
```

So if I turn on 'draw' mode, can it dispatch 'mousedown' event to main svg?

During draw mode, I want to draw line without any interrupt.(like MS "PowerPoint")

Is there any solution or do I need to change events handling?

Thanks for reading my questions.

Comment: You didn't tried anything yet.

Comment: @MaheerAli What do you mean I'm not trying anything?

Answer (score 0):

I solved myself.

My solution is

```
d3.selectAll('objects').style('pointer-events', 'none);
```

during drawing mode, I turn off all objects clickable.